# Bootstrap CSS Subitem not under parent and dropdown menu has unwanted space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a menu with a dropdownitem. When hovering the item the list appears, but I want the text with the background centered below the parent item. This is my first time building a dropdown menu, and it doesn't really work.

I've tried to find a solution but nothing really worked for me. Also, there is unwanted space on the left and I don't know how to get rid of it.

I'm using bootstrap, if that's relevant in any way.

Here you can see how it looks like. It's not directly under it's parent, I can't get the text centered and there is space on the left.

[image: Dropdownmenu]

HTML

```css
.navbar {
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background: #292657;
  border: none;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > ul {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #292657;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > ul > li {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 25px 40px 25px 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -45px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container" style="margin-left:50px;">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="">Startseite</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="ueber-mich/">Über&nbsp;mich</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#anker">Referenzen</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="maler-und-tapezierarbeiten/">Maler- und Tapezierarbeiten</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="fenster-und-tuerenanstrich">Türen und Fensteranstrich</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="spachtel-und-lasurtechniken/">Spachtel- und Lasurtechniken</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="fassadenanstrich/">Fassadenanstrich</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Dekorputze</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="renovierung/">Renovierungen</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="impressum/">Impressum</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Help would be highly appreciate, thanks a lot

Comment: Please make your snippet work so it looks like the images you've posted. I tried but there seems to be stuff missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the "unwanted space on left" is the default padding-left added by the browser, so I would add:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > ul{
  padding:0;
 }
```

After that, I would remove the negative margin `margin-left:-45px`

then you could adjust the padding of the first-level items and of the dropdown.
e.g.

```css
.navbar {
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #292657;
  border: none;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > ul {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #292657;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 40px;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > ul > li {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 25px 40px 25px 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container" style="margin-left:50px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">
                            Startseite
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="ueber-mich/">
                            Über&nbsp;mich
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#anker">
                            Referenzen
                        </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="maler-und-tapezierarbeiten/">Maler- und Tapezierarbeiten</a></li>
                            <li><a href="fenster-und-tuerenanstrich">Türen und Fensteranstrich</a></li>
                            <li><a href="spachtel-und-lasurtechniken/">Spachtel- und Lasurtechniken</a></li>
                            <li><a href="fassadenanstrich/">Fassadenanstrich</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Dekorputze</a></li>
                            <li><a href="renovierung/">Renovierungen</a></li>                   
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="impressum/">
                            Impressum
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
</nav>
```

Please note that your dropdown menu will not work on mobile (small screen) devices; If you perform a search for "bootstrap navbar multilevel" you'll find some ready-to-use bootstrap plugins.